# Fetch Data At every 2 Minutes SQL Lite

Tags: sqlite

Please can anyone help me in fetching data from my SQL Lite Table at every 2 minutes between my start time and stop time
I have two columns Data , TimeStamp and I am filtering between two timestamp and it is working fine but what I am trying to do is to result my data at every 2 minutes interval For example my start time is 2016-12-15 10:00:00 and stop time is 2016-12-15 10:10:00 the result should be 2016-12-15 10:00:00,2016-12-15 10:02:00,2016-12-15 10:04:00 ....

Comment: You question is broad and unclear, you should explain a little more what your issue is

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want data of my sql lite table at every 2 minutes inetrval

Comment: Let's give you a try... What tables+columns do you have? What SELECT do you make to fetch Timestamps?

Comment: I have two columns Data[String],TimeStamp[string in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] I want to write a query to select Data,TimeStamp From Table1 Where TimeStamp >= '2016-12-15 10:00:00' AND TimeSatmp <= '2016-12-15 10:10:00' at every two minutes interval so result will be A 2016-12-15 10:00:00 , B 2016-12-15 10:02:00,C 2016-12-15 10:04:00

Comment: This is still broad, what do you do with the data that need aggregation? My advice: go there: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7 create some sample data, save the fiddle and edit your question to add: 1/ the saved fiddle url 2/ your expected output for this data and *maybe*, someone will provide an answer.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.) Additional schema
information and where your attempts failed would also help us to help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add, to your `where` clause, an expression that looks for 2 minute boundaries:

```
strftime("%s", TimeStamp) % 120 = 0
```

This assumes you have data on exact, 2-minute boundaries. It will ignore data between those points.

`strftime("%s", TimeStamp)` converts your time stamp string into a single number representing the number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970. The `% 120` does modulo arithmetic resulting in 0 every 120 seconds. If you want minute boundaries, use 60. If you want hourly, use 3600.

What's more interesting -- and I've used this -- is to take all the data between boundaries and average them together:

```
SELECT CAST(strftime("%s", TimeStamp) / 120 AS INTEGER) * 120 as stamp, AVG(Data)
    FROM table
    WHERE TimeStamp >= '2016-12-15 10:00:00' AND
          TimeStamp < '2016-12-15 10:10:00'
    GROUP BY stamp;
```

This averages all data with timestamps in the same 2-minute "bin". The second date comparison is `<` rather than `<=` because then the last bin would only average one sample whereas the other bins would be averages of multiple values. You could also add `MAX(Data)` and `MIN(Data)` columns, if you want to know how much the data changed within each bin.

Comment: for odd minutes like 3 minutes,5minutes etc its not resulting right result

Comment: For that, you'd need to adjust the formula to "shift" to the odd minute boundaries: `CAST(strftime("%s", TimeStamp) / 120 - 60 AS INTEGER) * 120 + 60`

Comment: If you want each minute, then replace `120` with `60` in my answer.

Comment: minute boundaries are user dependent it can be even or odd

Comment: Then you'll have to create a prepared statement where the parameters are bindable. For instance, replace `120` with `(? * 60)`. The `?` is substituted with the number of minutes apart. The +/- `60` becomes another `?` so you can determine the offset from the base "minute".